# I uploaded multiple apks but Play console changes my app version codes for each of them but I have to set min version in dynamic links

Tags: android, version, google-play-console, firebase-dynamic-links, app-update

When I am uploading multiple apks for different abis to play store then play console changes my app version code for each apk to 4 digit no 1001, 2001 like this.

The problem is I have dynamic link in my app and I need to specify the minimum app version in the firebase dynamic links in the website and now I am confused because play store has given 4 version codes and dynamic links accepts only 1...what should I do...I need to upload 4 apk for abi and also mention the minimum apk version in the firebase console for dynamic links.

I have opted in for signing in play console.

I have attached screenshot of play console and firebase dynamic link console bellow

[image: screenshot of play console]

[image: Firebase console dynamic links]

Answer (score 1):

I would use an Android App Bundle (.aab) as this saves your app size through optimising APKs for each device configuration. It has become the recommended way to publish apps on Google Play.

This would help solve your problem as you would only upload one file and you would have only one version code which you would enter into firebase dynamic links.

More information here: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle

Comment: also helpful is https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources